# In iOS how to detect what html elements are visible on the screen as user scrolls through WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

One of the views in my iOS app is a WKWebView. I've got a static html page that I'm loading into WKWebView via `loadHTMLString` method. The html document that's getting loaded consists of several paragraphs of text. As the user scrolls through the text I need to detect that this block of text was "visible" on the screen and mark it as read. Once all text is scrolled through the user is allowed to proceed further.

I understand the solution to this would be some kind of combination of swift and javascript code. I've read about WKUserContentController and ways to post messages from javascript and receiving them via:

`func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)`

But can't yet figure out how to make it work as described above. What would be a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add postMessage using `WKUserScript`

```
let script = WKUserScript(source: "window.print = function() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.print.postMessage('print') }", injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
    webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "print")


let url = URL(string: link)!
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(urlRequest)
```

Now you can receive the message like this

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if message.name == "print" {
            printCurrentPage()
        }
}
```

Comment: This one I was written to handle print method from web view, you can change WKUserScript asper your requirements.